# Stop user typing date in input with datepicker control

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a created a jquery datepicker. I want the user to select to the date which is greater than or equal to current date so I have used `mindate: 0`. This disables all the previous the dates.

However through the input field the user can type a previous date. How can I disable the input field but not the datepicker?

```
$('#DateFrom1').datepicker('setDate', 'today');
$("#DateFrom1").datepicker({
    minDate: 0
});
```

[image: datepicker]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the input field `readonly` so that users cannot edit it directly. Also note that you're currently attempting to set the date of the datepicker control before you instantiate it; swap the order of those statements.

```js
$("#DateFrom1").datepicker({
    minDate: 0
}).datepicker('setDate', 'today');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">

<input type="text" id="DateFrom1" readonly="true" />
```

Comment: @rooter I'm not sure what you mean by 'anymore' as the example above has the field set to `readonly` and it opens the date picker absolutely fine.

Comment: Sorry. The problem is with bootstrap datetimepicker, not jquery datetimepicker. I didn't realize they were different.

Comment: Ah, no problem :)